# Creating a list filled with new instances of an object

Tags: c#, linq, list

What's the best way to create a list with an arbitrary number of instances of the same object? i.e is there a more compact or efficient way to do the following?

```
static List<MyObj> MyObjs = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(i => new MyObj())
    .ToList();
```

(`Enumerable.Repeat` would give me ten references to the same object, so I don't think it would work.)

Comment: I don't see any issues with your current approach...

Comment: I'm not saying there's an issue... it just feels like a hack.

Comment: "it just feels like a hack." Why, not at all! This beats a `for` loop hands down :-)

Comment: This really does seem like the best way. I mean, you could still use a `for` loop, or reflection's `Activator`.

Comment: My guess is that `Enumerable.Range` is just a `for` loop if you decompile it.

Comment: I prefer `Enumerable.Repeat(new MyObj(), 100).ToList();`

Comment: @CharlieBrown if you want different instances of `MyObj`, you cannot use `Repeat`.  It will give you the same instance 100 times.

Comment: _instances of the same object_? I think it should be instances of the same **type**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This wouldn't be hard to implement as an iterator:

```
IEnumerable<T> CreateItems<T> (int count) where T : new() {
    return CreateItems(count, () => new T());
}

IEnumerable<T> CreateItems<T> (int count, Func<T> creator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        yield return creator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Edited to reflect that this method **does not** work.

I was curious about your comment about `Enumerable.Repeat`, so I tried it.

```
//do not use!
List<object> myList = Enumerable.Repeat(new object(), 100).ToList();
```

I confirmed that they do all share the same reference like the OP mentioned.

Comment: You are overwriting the instances when you do `myList[i] = ...`.  Make a class Foo, with a property Bar, then change Bar, you will see that it changes for every index.

Comment: @cadrell0 thank you for your comment. You are correct - I threw myself off there. I'll leave my answer here merely as a lesson for any one else on what not to do.

Comment: But a select() added let's you create new objects for every element.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the answer is "no". Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what is wrong with a for loop in this case. At the very least, we can presize the capacity of the list. That might not be important for 100 objects, but the size is arbitrary.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static int Capacity = 100;
    static List<MyObj> MyObjs = new List<MyObj>(Capacity);

    static MyClass() {
       for( var i = 0; i < Capacity; i++ ) {
          MyObjs.Add(new MyObj());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `ToList` uses the `List(IEnumerable<T> items)` constructor of `List<T>`, which I believe is a little faster than calling `Add` for each item.  It is at the very least the same.  `Range` uses a `for` loop internally.  Your solution is at best, the same performance, but more code.

Comment: The .Select method must necessarily create a new Enumeration since the type has changed from an int to a MyObj. It must also invoke an anonymous method 100 times and finally convert this all into a List<MyObj>.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx  Both Range and Select use `yield return`.  Because execution is deferred to the point that `ToList` is called, the results are only enumerated once, which happens while building the list.

Comment: But simply deferring the execution doesn't prevent the execution. The final ToList call will still trigger 100 calls to Func<int,MyObj>(i) { return new MyObj() }.

Granted, it's done efficiently, but it HAS to have some additional overhead. Still, if I were coding this, and if the capacity was small, I would opt for the one-liner as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the enumerable as a base and use select to create the new objects:

```
List<object> myList = Enumerable.Repeat(null, 100).Select(_ => new object()).ToList();
```

you can attach a debugger, the `new` is executed every time.
This is almost the same as your code, but you don't have to provide a fake range.
You only provide a `null` as fake object you want to repeat...