# c# instantiate multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

So I want to instantiate a chunk of objects to gain some speed instead of creating each item with the new keyword. Eg. in c++ you'd use the code below:

```
ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[1000];
```

But I can't get my head around how to do this in c#. If I excecute the code above I just get 1000 pointers.(I guess since they are null)

My goal is to avoid having to call new 1000 times

Edit:
Made a testprogram in c++ to try to show what I want to achieve in c#.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        m_pVector = NULL;
    }
    void setVector(vector<string>* pVector)
    {
        m_pVector = pVector;
    }
    void deleteVector()
    {
        vector<string>* temp = m_pVector;
        m_pVector = NULL;
        delete temp;
    }
private:
    vector<string>* m_pVector;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int size = 100000;
    A* A1s = new A[size]();
    A* A2s = new A[size]();

    long int start1=0;
    long int diff1=0;
    long int start2=0;
    long int diff2=0;

    vector<string>* mVectors = NULL;

    for(int c1=0;c1<10;c1++)
    {
        if(c1>0)
        {
            vector<string>* temp1 = mVectors;
            mVectors = NULL;
            delete[] temp1;
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            {
                A2s[i].deleteVector();
            }
        }

        start1 = clock();
        mVectors = new vector<string>[size]();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            A1s[i].setVector(&mVectors[i]);
        }
        diff1 = clock() - start1;

        start2 = clock();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            A2s[i].setVector(new vector<string>());
        }
        diff2 = clock() - start2;

        cout<<"1:"<<diff1<<" 2:"<<diff2<<" diff:"<<diff2-diff1<<endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

So createing a chunk of data is allot faster than creating new in each loop.
And I'd like to do the same in c# but I can't figure out how to create the chunk of data.

Comment: Why would you create 1000 pointers? It seems, well, pointless.

Comment: I'd say [answer is no](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17865166/1997232).

Comment: I think you'd be hardpressed to find any performance increase in C# with this type of approach unless your object init had some sort of drastic performance hit associated with it (such as querying a database), and even then you'd have to deal with the cost at some point.  I have a suspicion the compiler would heavily optimize this for you anyway.

Comment: If there were such a thing it would still need to call the constructor, which is what `new` does ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The references are used in c# instead of pointers. So why don`t you just create 1000 of them in a loop?

Comment: Youd be better of describing *what* you are trying to do rather than *how* .  an arrary of LVIs is almost useless

Comment: Well I don't want to call new in each loop since it's allot slower. Never claimed that LVIs are useless just took them as an example, could be an arbitrary class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in this C++ code:

```
ListViewItem[] items = new ListViewItem[1000];
```

The object constructor (initialization) will be called `1000` times.
That's it, there are a *hidden* loop.

The only advantage indeed is that the memory allocation is only done once.

- 1 allocation.
- n initializations.

There is no equivalent things in C#. The allocation and the initialization are done together, one object at a time, and it's done when you call `new`.

Your are stuck to:

- 1 allocation.
- 1 initialization.
- repeat.

So use [for-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ch45axte.aspx) to achieve it, it's the standard way to achieve it:

```
var items = new ListViewItem[1000];
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    items[i] = new ListViewItem();
}
```

You can also use linq to impress your partner:

```
var array = new object[1000];
Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).Select(i => array[i] = new object());
```

Comment: It's quicker since I'm creating a chunk of data and not calling new in each loop iteration.

Comment: I never claimed that it would be faster with less code and could you please explain the points you've made? They don't make much sense as is.

Comment: Ok. Well that's a bummer. Thanks for your answer! : )